# How to code/run Ruby on Chromebook

Tags: ruby, web, openshift, chromebook

On the desktop, I can use a text editor with the ruby interpreter to run everything, but there isn't an interpreter available for Chromebook. Is there any online software/program/webapp that would let me run Ruby code or emulate it? Kind of like Codeacademy where you put your stuff into the one section and it displays the results in another 'console' section.

I found something called OpenShift, and I'm wondering if it would let me upload a `.rb` file and have it run or something so I can see what I'm making.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, sawa. I'm kind of new to StackExchange (this is my 2nd post ever) and don't know how to ask effective questions yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One great online code editor to keep in mind is Github. You can create and edit files right in the browser. You could then sign up for a free Heroku account or the free tier of Amazon EC2. Heroku can pull directly from your Github project. EC2 can give you a complete environment to work in, though you'll have to set it up yourself just like you would on your own machine.

Comment: The Heroku tip is kind of what I was hoping to get done with OpenShift. I'm fine with doing it w/ Heroku instead. I've looked all over for a tutorial on how to do it; wondering if you know of any to do that sort of thing? I'm very new to this kind of stuff, and haven't used a PaaS before or anything involving servers or anything fancy like that.

Comment: Well, getting an app that is in a github repo onto Heroku in not "hard" at all. But getting your account set up, installing the Heroku tools on your laptop or EC2 instance, setting up your DB on Heroku, etc... these are all task that you'll have to take on by reading the documentation at Heroku. No way around it. Heroku's docs are really thorough.

Answer (score 6):

Install linux with [Crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton)  and you can run/install libs etc as you need to

Just found another way...run [Servers Ultimate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.serversultimate) from your Android phone or tablet and access through the hotpoint wifi

Answer (score 5):

Here are some web IDEs that support Ruby.

- [Cloud9 IDE](https://c9.io/)
- [Cloud IDE](https://codenvy.com/)
- [Koding.com](https://koding.com/)
- [Codeanywhere](https://codeanywhere.com/)

There's also a Chrome extension called [SourceKit](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sourcekit/iieeldjdihkpoapgipfkeoddjckopgjg?hl=en), which is a bit like TextMate, but saves files directly on Dropbox. However, that alone will not be enough to actually run the code...

Comment: +1 for the chrome version..I didn't aware of this.

Comment: Yes, I downloaded SourceKit a while ago to try it out when I needed a text editor for HTML and CSS, but after agreeing to connect to Dropbox it would just redirect to about:blank and nothing more. I tried reinstalling it again just now; same issue, it won't connect to Dropbox.

Also, Codenvy doesn't let you run the code: http://docs.codenvy.com/user/supported-languages/

Comment: I use to write code on a chromebook like this it was interesting experience. http://www.eq8.eu/blogs/18-chromebook-for-web-developers

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, Try here [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_overview.htm).

Click **Try it**

[image]

[image]

Comment: The limitation of this is you can't load any libraries that aren't already in Standard Lib. Try to `require '...` something and if will give you an error.

Comment: @Beartech Yes. only core and standard lib will be supported..

Answer (score 1):

Nitrous has a powerful chrome application with native keyboard shortcuts for the IDE, and a number of popular starter templates, including ruby. The first container is 100% free, you can check out the chrome application here:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nitrous-pro/efdcneeepllhjlbejkfnaolelbpdacai

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine is a Chromebook user / software engineer and I'm thinking of following him.

He knows VIM and does all of his development on a linux instance that costs $10/mo at linode.com.  I think the Chromebook paradigm is that you keep your activities inside of Chrome.

You can lose a lot of time keeping a development environment on your laptop, regardless of its OS.

Meanwhile the VPS can be used from anywhere, even when your laptop dies or you forgot your power cable at home.

If you're new to software development then I bet Cloud9 is a better place to start, even though I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's also very easy to install linux on a Chromebook these days.  See, for example, the Arch wiki explaining the process:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chrome_OS_devices

Answer (score 0):

First install anaconda.

Then `conda install -c ruby-lang ruby`

Source: https://anaconda.org/ruby-lang/ruby